# UIKBTree crash in iOS11

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsdictionary, ios11

I have unexpected crashes in my application that affect only iOS 11. It happens approximately 50 a day. I can't reproduce this error. I can't find any information about this crash. Is there anyone else with this issue?

Crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x000000016eedbfe0

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x186079448 malloc_zone_calloc + 74
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x186079424 calloc + 40
2   libobjc.A.dylib                0x185a4845c class_createInstance + 76
3   CoreFoundation                 0x186535ce8 __CFAllocateObject2 + 24
4   CoreFoundation                 0x1863f5a58 +[__NSDictionaryM __new:::::] + 120
5   CoreFoundation                 0x186419c44 +[NSDictionary dictionary] + 44
6   UIKit                          0x190248c3c -[UIKBTree initWithType:] + 136
7   UIKit                          0x190248e34 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 92
8   CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
9   CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
10  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
11  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
12  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
13  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
14  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
15  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
16  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
17  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
18  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
19  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
20  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
21  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
22  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
23  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
24  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
25  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
26  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
27  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
28  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
29  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
30  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
31  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
32  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
33  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
34  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
35  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
36  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
37  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
38  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
39  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
40  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
41  CoreFoundation                 0x186439c80 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 320
42  CoreFoundation                 0x186564794 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 180
43  UIKit                          0x190248e74 -[UIKBTree copyWithZone:] + 156
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? If so, it may either help someone find the issue, or help you submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @Stephen   I think crash may happen when the keyboard evokes. I do not know what code causes this problem.  This is crash log http://crashes.to/s/73bb052b3e1

Comment: It definitely looks like something recursive is happening. I’ve seen similar repeating crash logs when we were calling some code in a endless loop. I would make sure that no code called when the keyboard evokes tries to evoke the keyboard again. Especially if you are using some custom keyboard code.

Comment: i got the same crash trace and happened when showing the keyboard, don't know why.